# Does reliability/validity apply on manually summed items?

Tags: reliability, validity, sum

For a subscale of mine, it showed a reliability in the 0.6 range which is in the 'questionable' range and it showed an AVE (convergent validity) of just 0.3. Now I know that it will be perceived as a badly conceived construct but bear with me. If I use this construct as a dependent variable in the multiple regression analysis, the independent ones (much better reliability but still less than 0.5 of AVE) will have a moderate significant relationship with the predicted outcome (which is expected). My question:

How valid is such a result (is it attenuated and could have been even better? Please note that all regression assumptions were met)? If I decide to just sum up the items manually (like literally summing up the scale score by an addition function), can this provides a much cleaner composite despite different loadings? (i.e. free of reliability and validity issues to be used for cross-checking of the results)

Comment: What do you mean by "the independent ones" and "predicted outcome", simply variables? What qualifies as moderate significant relationship in your case? I think more information about your variables will be helpful.

Comment: independent ones = independent variables (predictors). Predicted outcome = dependent variable. Moderate sig. = Beta at 0.4.

Comment: Acock (2013) does not recommend using summative score when loadings vary considerably; also the items are rarely equivalent. I think using constructs/factors is a better strategy. Maybe you can fit CFA (separately for factors) and check for goodness-of-fit statistics for more information. But if there are reliability/validity issues, I suggest addressing these before the analysis.

Comment: I see. One question: If you're only doing an EFA/PCA just to use the scores in a regression analysis. Now it is known that PCA accounts for more variance and so would it make sense here if I calculate the AVEs? Because AVEs are related to factor analysis and so I am only doing a PCA which clearly shows that the variance explained is above 50% but using FA/AVEs will return a variance below 50%. What is relevant in my case? Would it make sense if I report the AVEs being less than 50% even though I am doing a PCA?

Comment: AVE measures variance explained by the latent factor structure versus the variance due to (measurement) error. Now if this is the case, it doesn't make sense to talk about AVE for PCA; there is a reason PCA accounts for more variance: it accounts for total variance, meaning that it confounds common and unique variance. However to calculate AVE, you need to decompose variance into common variance and unique variance. You might  want to look at other reliability/validity measures. But I think the important issue is to justify your decision to use one (PCA, EFA) and not the other.

Comment: Yes. From the beginning of my research, I indicated the choice of PCA for a few reasons (first time exploratory research of the topic in my country, exploring components for regression and not for CFA, desire for total variance, problems associated with FA: I built a few arguments). Also, how can I really prove the convergent validity of a PCA component? In worst case, if one gets an AVE of 0.3 for his constructs (but CRs > 0.6 as required), is his research doomed even if he finds a few significant expected relationships and cites the infamous quote of AVE being a strict measure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47729/discussion-between-tahir-and-r-as).